# How to remove old data and bind new data to a table while using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have a custom directive like this:

```
<table  id="usertbl" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="
 position: relative;
    top: 27px;
">
  <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>gender</th>
        <th>state</th>
        <th>zip</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>mobile</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="x in users">
    <td>{{ x.fName }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.lName }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.gender }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.state }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.zip }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.mobile }}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clickFunc(x.email)">Delete Customer</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>


 http.get("getallusers.do",{ params:{pageno:count,pageSize:2}}).then(function(response) {
                    //First function handles success
                    scope.users = response.data;)}
```

One next button is there each time clicking it will fetch 10 records from the db, but each time the 10 record is added to the existing 10 record in the ui table. i want only new 10 record to be added in the table .

Comment: As per your current code `scope.users = response.data;` in OP. As `scope.users` is not an array it will always have new set of records while you are making an **`API`** call. 

It will always have new set of records when you click on **`Next`** button.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the array and then push the new data as below

```
 scope.users =[];
 scope.users = response.data;
```

Comment: Each time the new data is coming from server .

Comment: Why do you need to do this response.data is a new array you are instantiating an array then pointing users at a different object?

Comment: I want to remove the old rows from that table and display the new data by ng-repeat .

Answer (score 0):

You have to methods to do this

First, you can clear the array and then push the new data

```
 scope.users = [];
 scope.users = response.data;
```

Second, you can splice and insert new data

```
 //This will recreate the array as well
 scope.users.splice(0, scope.users.length, ...response.data);
```

So it will be like this

```
http.get("getallusers.do",{ params:{pageno:count,pageSize:2}}).then(function(response) {
                    //First function handles success
                    scope.users = []
                    scope.users = response.data;
                    //OR
                    scope.users.splice(0, scope.users.length, ...response.data);
             )}
```

**UDPATE**

What I am assuming from your comments is you are trying to remove values which are same in response.data and users.

You could do something like this.

```
scope.users = scope.users.filter(function(obj) { 
               return response.data.indexOf(obj) == -1; });
```

Comment: Its iterating over new data in ng-repeat but its appending to the old data. i want to remove the old rows and append the new rows in to that table

Comment: @RajanikantaPradhan You are getting the old data in that response.data? Because by doing what and other have told you will remove the old data from users. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.users = response.data;`

```
  $scope.users = response.data;
  $scope.$apply()
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3a6LLmuj/1/)